# Can't enable CSM mode or Fast Boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, uefi

I have an ASUS UX302LA laptop and its been working great. A little while back I was loading different OSs on it, and had to disable Fast Boot and Secure Boot Control, and enable CSM mode. After a while of using these random OSs I just installed windows 8.1, but never bothered to change these settings back. Today I was doing some tweaks on my laptop and tried to reactivate Fast Boot, but instead of booting it now does not recognize either drive (booting hard drive or cache SSD) and simply returns to the bios. I restored back to the bios defaults, same issue.

Short of doing a full OS reinstall, is there anything I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Fast Boot and Capability Mode are mutually exclusive features.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: If you installed Windows 8.1 while in CSM, you've likely got an MBR disk/partition, which won't be compatible with UEFI and Fast Boot, which will require GPT . . . you can find guides to convert from MBR to GPT, e.g. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725671.aspx

Comment: Yeah, following a guide is definitely a good idea. This guide, however, requires you to remove all partitions. Better follow [my guide](http://superuser.com/a/874473/219095). :D

Comment: @DanielB - hah, I should have paid more attention to what I linked.  Didn't realize it was a full re-format with data loss . . . whoops :P